# Setting center and scale during spherical uv layout

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, mathematics

I'd like to map part of an equirectangular image to a cuboid mesh, in order that the texture view from an arbitrary POV appears without distortion.  Both the mesh and its uv layout will be used for a projection mapping environment, hence the question.

The image below shows the mesh, and a proxy sphere to mark the location I'd like to view the equirectangular image without distortion.

[image]

I'm using Blender's [spherical uv unwrapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/mapping_types.html), which is close, but I can't see any controls exposed to allow me to translate or scale the spherical projection itself.  Note that I'm not talking about scaling or translating the UV islands, after projection.  Instead, I want to control the position from which the spherical projection itself is centered.

For reference, Maya uses a [manipulator tool](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-2B74F60D-B6B5-4794-BDC1-17E2FB06F393-htm.html) to position and scale spherical UV projection.

I'm hoping there is a way to translate and scale spherical projection in Blender, similar to the Maya example.

Comment: I have no clue how Maya works. But it looks to me you are looking for a tool like the ["UV project" modifer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html)

Comment: You can also transform the texture space in the view directly. 
In Edit Mode, you can use Mesh > Transform > Move Texture Space (Shift + T) or Mesh > Transform > Scale Texture Space (Alt + Shift + T)

Comment: Thanks @cegaton, your suggestion makes sense, since 'emitting' a uv map from a single point would allow control for the center of the projection, as I asked.  Naïvely, it seems that emitting uvs from a point at the center of given sphere would  be equivalent to spherical mapping.  I'll need to make a few trials to see if I'm interpreting you correctly.

Comment: Excellent point @Ben, I didn't know these options were available.  I've made a few trials, translating the texture space and re-projecting, but the center of the resulting spherical mapping does not seem to move.  That is, I can control the projection seam where the unit square wraps, but not the central point from which the spherical projection is made.